# pthread_mutex_trylock segment fault

Tags: c, locking, pthreads, segmentation-fault, deadlock

I have struggling a week to fix a program , in the begining i got SIGBUS , but after many attempts still the program gets SIGSEGV segment fault , In bellow i post the seg fault log + source codes. would really appreciate if experts help me to fix this segment fault error. any advice is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

```
LL_NODE *ll_prepend(LLIST *l, void *obj)
{
    if (l && obj) {
//line bellow is module-datastruct-llist.c:167 
//mentioned in segment-fault log as frame 3

      if (!ll_lock(l)) return NULL;
        LL_NODE *new;
        if(!cs_malloc(&new,sizeof(LL_NODE), -1)) return NULL;
        new->obj = obj;
        new->nxt = l->initial;
        l->initial = new;
        if (!l->last)
            l->last = l->initial;
        l->count++;
        ll_unlock(l);
        return new;
    }
    return NULL;
}






int32_t ll_lock(LLIST *l)
{
    int32_t res = 1;
   res=cs_trylock(&l->lock);

//line bellow is module-datastruct-llist.c:51  
//mentioned in segment-fault log as frame 2

  while (l && !l->flag && res) {
        cs_debug_mask(D_TRACE, "trylock ll_lock wait");
        cs_sleepms(fast_rnd()%5 + 1);
    }
    return !res;
}







int32_t cs_trylock(pthread_mutex_t *mutex){

    if(!mutex) return -1;
        int32_t result, oldtype;
        /* Make sure that we won't get interrupted while getting the lock */
        pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED, &oldtype);

//line bellow is oscam-simples.c:1233  
//mentioned in segment-fault log as frame 1

        if((result=pthread_mutex_trylock(mutex)) == 0){

            struct s_client *cl = cs_preparelock(cur_client(), mutex);
            if(cl)
                cl->mutexstore_used++;
        }
        pthread_setcanceltype(oldtype, NULL);
        pthread_testcancel();
        return result;
    }

// in this function &l->lock is initialized   
LLIST *ll_create()
{
    LLIST *l = cs_malloc(&l, sizeof(LLIST), 0);
    pthread_mutex_init(&l->lock, NULL);
    return l;
}



Segment fault log :
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to LWP 1905]
0x2979b7ba in pthread_mutex_trylock () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x2979b7ba in pthread_mutex_trylock () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00410d98 in cs_trylock (mutex=0x247373a4) at oscam-simples.c:1233
#2  0x0043d4aa in ll_lock (l=0x24737398) at module-datastruct-llist.c:51
#3  0x0043d956 in ll_prepend (l=0x24737398, obj=0x4a2410)
    at module-datastruct-llist.c:167
#4  0x0040a66e in get_cw (client=0x4daa80, er=0x5063a0) at oscam.c:2645
#5  0x00439754 in dvbapi_process_input (demux_id=0, filter_num=0,
    buffer=0x2a98bb60 "\201q=", len=320) at module-dvbapi.c:1634
#6  0x0043c866 in stapi_read_thread (sparam=0x4d1558) at module-dvbapi.c:2441
#7  0x29799486 in ?? () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
Backtrace stopped: frame did not save the PC
(gdb) info args
No symbol table info available.
```

Comment: An unrelated tip: You should refrain from naming variables things like `new` or `class` etc. This is because these are keywords in C++, and even though you might use a pure C compiler someone else in the future may try to use your code in a C++ compiler and will have errors.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Should you also refrain from naming things `finally`, `super`, or `transient`? What about `yield`, `pass`, or `lambda`? C is not C++, and there is no reason that C code should ever be compiled with a C++ compiler; in fact, a C++ compiler cannot compile the vast majority of correct idiomatic C.

Comment: @R.. I've heard and read about lots of people using a C++ compiler for their C code, mostly because of the stricter type checking. I think it's also not uncommon to start with a C program, and then convert it to C++ step by step (starting with "C with classes" and all that).

Comment: Well perhaps we'll have to agree to disagree; I think that's well beyond the boundary of "misguided". Even if you are doing that, you're writing the language that is the intersection of C and C++, not C, and I don't think it's valid advice for somebody who's programming in C any more than it would be valid to tell them they should be writing a polyglot that runs as either C or Perl... :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from `l->lock` which is never initialised and thus contains non-NULL unusable garbage.

Try adding `l->lock = NULL;` or initialize it properly by creating the mutex.

Comment: Thanks for reply . but well , when i try to add               new->lock = NULL;                                                  i get compile error  : ‘LL_NODE’ has no member named ‘lock’
 any  advice , is highly appreciated

Comment: You're right, I misread your code and went over that detail. Have you tried initializing `l->lock`? Can you post code where you do so? I edited my answer so it says `l->lock`

Comment: tnx for reply but still after adding                          l->lock = NULL; still gets anther compile error :error: incompatible types in assignment
here is the complete source codes : module-datastruct.c: http://www.streamboard.tv/oscam/browser/trunk/module-datastruct-llist.c?rev=5375   oscam-simples.c:                                   http://www.streamboard.tv/oscam/browser/trunk/oscam-simples.c?rev=5375                                                  and here is global defenitions :                                    http://www.streamboard.tv/oscam/browser/trunk/globals.h?rev=5375

Comment: as above link module-datastruct : line 39 confirms            `LLIST *ll_create(){`                                         `LLIST *l = cs_malloc(&l, sizeof(LLIST),0);` `pthread_mutex_init(&l->lock,NULL);`                          `return l;}`                    so it seems , it properly initalized by mutex and problem comes from other part of code , my guess is oscam-simples.c :1233 , pthread-trylock cause it , any advice is appreciated

Comment: Well i can't run Valgrind in my os (Which the os is Linux sh4 , unfortunately, valgrind has not supported sh4 Cpu)  but this segment-fault were also reported by users who are use other os (which is supported by valgrind too , the bug might be tough, hope one experts could help me to fix it...